How to make an auto-timestamped row in Google Sheets
I found a guide for a timestamp column that works great. But I'd like it as a header row, and can't get it to work. I'm attempting to get a horizontal auto-timestamp header.
Here is my code:
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange ('M' + e.range.rowStart)
    .setValue (new Date())
    .setNumberFormat ('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MMam/pm');
}

And here is my edited version:
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange ('1' + e.range.columnStart)
    .setValue (new Date())
    .setNumberFormat ('MM/dd/yyyy');
}

The goal is to populate row 1 when a cell in the same column is edited.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Use getRange(row,column) Instead
Instead of using A1Notation, why don't you use getRange().
I made some minor adjustments to your code:
From:
sh.getRange ('1' + e.range.columnStart)

To:
sh.getRange (1 , e.range.getColumn())

I opted for the getColumn() function instead of columnStart(). This ensures that the header will automatically update with the current timestamp whenever you make edits below.
Here's the full code:
function onEdit(e){
const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
sh.getRange (1 , e.range.getColumn()) // I modified this line
.setValue (new Date())
.setNumberFormat ('MM/dd/yyyy');
}

Sample Output:


Note: I assumed that your Spreadsheet looked like this.

References:

getColumn()
getRange(row, column)


If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. Feel free to clarify below if this was not the result you want.

You are welcome! If this resolves your question, please click the check mark (✓) on the left to accept the answer and consider upvoting it. This helps others in the community who might have similar questions know that this solution works. If you cannot see the accept button, please let me know. For more information, you can refer to (stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

@SusanKatz e.range.columnStart returns a number, so '1' + e.range.columnStart will return something like '11', '12', '13', etc. None of these values could be used alone as the parameter for getRange. To use a single value it should be 'A1, 'B1', 'C1'. One alternative is to convert e.range.columnStart to a letter.
